# ¿Cuál es el origen del modismo "es equis" para decir que algo no es malo ni bueno, sino "más o menos"?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, modismos, etimología, méxico

Una amiga de Monterrey, México a veces dice "Ah, es equis" para decir que no le apasiona cierta cosa.  Ejemplo:

> **A:** ¿Te gustan los tacos que se venden en la esquina?
>
> **B:** Meeh... son equis.

¿Cuál es el origen de ese modismo? Y ¿Dónde se usa ese modismo?

Comment: En Colombia en la zona de Cali tambien he visto que lo usan

Comment: Nunca lo he escuchado (Argentina).

Comment: @c.p.: I have edited the question to focus on the origin of the phrase, rather than its regional usage.

Comment: Por regionalizarlo más: en Venezuela se usa bastante. Aunque ahora también se usa nulo/a cuando se habla más de ignoro que de indiferencia.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Ser equis* tiene su origen en *ser x* en el sentido algebraico: una incógnita, o algo que podría tomar cualquier valor, en otras palabras, *algo desconocido*.  Es decir, *ser equis* denota *ausencia de popularidad* o *mediocridad*,  es lo mismo que *ser gris*, *no sobresalir* y *no ser importante*, o como @JoseMaria dice, *dos dos* o *dos tres* (ni excelente ni malo). En el ejemplo, la respuesta de *B* denota indiferencia:

> **B:** No me importaría ir a comer esos tacos, pero no me muero de ganas de ir a comerlos.

Por otro lado dicha expresión no se limita a ser adjetivo, sino que es también usada como sigue:

> **Ejemplo:** Madre a su hija mimada le dice
>   *-(M')Hijita, ¿vas a salir con esa ropa a la calle?*
>   *- Ay, equis mamá.* (i.e. ¿a quién le importará?)

Su **origen** puede verse también como une extrapolación a la cuarta acepción en el [DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/equis):

> equis.
>   1. f. Nombre de la letra x.
>   2. f. Nombre del signo de la incógnita en los cálculos.
>   3. (Por las figuras en forma de equis que recorren su espinazo). f. Col. Serpiente cuyo veneno es casi siempre mortal.
>   **4. adj. Se dice de un número desconocido o indiferente. Necesito una cantidad equis, o equis pesetas.**
>   estar alguien hecho una ~.
>   1. loc. verb. coloq. Estar borracho y dar traspiés cruzando las piernas e imitando la forma de la equis.

Es un vocablo usado, sobre todo por los jóvenes. No me imagino a mi abuelita ni a mis padres diciéndolo. Sobre su extensión, no sólo en el Norte, sino en todo México (al menos) y, según @EmilioGort, en Cali, Colombia.

Comment: Me parece que su uso es extendido por todo México. Estoy de acuerdo con la respuesta de @c.p. y sólo para complementarla acorde con la pregunta original te puedo decir que para indicar que algo no es ni bueno ni malo sino ¨mas o menos¨, en México igual es muy usado coloquialmente "dos tres(2-3)" o "dos dos(2-2)" para hacer referencia a que supera la calidad de malo pero no llega a ser muy bueno.

Answer (score 0):

Lo de Equis viene de las quinielas de futbol: 1-X-2. La X es el empate. por eso tb se dice 2-2.
No es la incógnita, sino el empate. me da igual, ni bueno ni malo, equis.